# How to send a file from Django to Gmail?

Tags: django, file, email, django-forms, gmail

There is a `feedback` form in which the user can write a `text` message and attach the `file`.

This form is sent to managers by mail (`gmail`, for example).

Is there any way to make this file come to mail in its normal form (in a `preview`, for example) so that you can `immediately see` or `download` it?

For now, I'm just sending a file link in the message.

Comment: You can attach a file to an [`EmailMessage`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects).

Comment: `expected bytes-like object, not FieldFile`

Comment: If you've already saved the file (seems you're using a model with `FileField`), then use `.attach_file()` and pass it the file `path`. Would be better to update your question with the code so we can be more specific.

Comment: Alternatively, open the file and pass it to `attach`: `file.open(); msg.attach(filename=file.name, content=file.read()); file.close()`

Comment: @dirkgroten Which method is better?

Comment: no difference I'd say. If you had the file already open, e.g. when the file has just been uploaded and you're saving it to the model, then you could use the second method, so as not to have to re-read it from disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help **@dirkgroten**

```
def send_contact_us_notification(file, name: str, email: str, body: str, phone='', nda=False):
    try:
        file = settings.MEDIA_URL[1:] + str(contact_form.file)
        from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
        msg = EmailMessage('Subject of the Email', 'Body of the email', 'dinamo.mutu111@gmailcom', ['dimaonlyvit@gmail.com'])
        msg.attach_file(file)
        msg.send()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```